Why we use the helping verb "do" to form questions and negative statements when the main verb is of type action?
What is the reason in using the verb "do"? On negative sentences, why we don't leave just the negation "not" with the main verb, as: "I not write", instead of "I do not write". The same for interrogative ones, switching just the verb before the subject: "Ride I bike?"
My first thought, is that it has to deal with its basic meaning: the subject is doing something.

There’s no real “reason” beyond That’s Just the Way English Is.
